# Selenium WebDrive wait by xpath not returning submit button

Tags: c#, selenium

I could have swore this would be easy as pie, but I might be missing something.

Here is the html
 `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Here is my code

```
 public static void _SeleniumRealWaitByInputType(InternetExplorerDriver driver, string value)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//input[@type='" + value + "']")));
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure");
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is me calling it

`WebDriverWaits._SeleniumRealWaitByInputType(driver, "Submit");`
and just in case it's case sensitive
`WebDriverWaits._SeleniumRealWaitByInputType(driver, "submit");`

However this object is never returned.  What am I missing?  I'm using IE Driver.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a void method returns nothing? What do you expect to get?

Comment: @Saifur Well I know the webpage does have the html that i'm looking for in it. `<input type="submit" value="Submit">  What I expect is to remain in this void until the element is found, hence the while loop then break.  What's happening is the condition for the wait isnt found in 5 seconds, so it'll throw an exception.  Which is planned so it maintains itself in the while loop.  The code works as I intend, what's not making sense is how come the element is never found

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can improve couple of things here.

=> You do not want to use Static delay and Explicit wait together. That defeats the purpose of using Explicit wait.

=> Probably do not need to write another method just to find ONE element if that's the case. In case just use Explicit wait. If that's not the case and you want to create a generic method to use somewhere else then I would 
rewrite it as follows:

```
public IWebElement WaitForElement(IWebDriver driver, string value)
{
    By xPath = By.XPath("//input[@type='" + value + "']");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    //Explicit wait should be enough in this case and do a DOM polling 
    //regularly to see if the element exist and until it finds it for 
    //most 10 second
    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(xPath);
    });

    return myDynamicElement;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the problem still remains.  The input cannot be found